# Set Default Shipping Option for specific User Group

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, shipping

I need to set the default shipping option for one specific usergroup but I cannot figure out how to do that.

What I currently have that is not working is:

```
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="shippingMethodHandle" value="{{ handle }}"
    {% if handle == cart.shippingMethodHandle %}
      checked

    {#
      // set default shipping option for distributors
      #}
    {% elseif
      cart.shippingMethodHandle == 'regularFreightPrepayAndAddToPurchaseOrder' and
      (currentUser.isInGroup('distributor') or currentUser.isInGroup('distributorA')) %}
    %}
      checked
    {% endif %}

    />
    <strong>{{ method.name }}</strong>

    {# display price fro users not in distributers/resellers #}
    {% if not currentUser.isInGroup('distributor')
      and not currentUser.isInGroup('distributorA')
      and not currentUser.isInGroup('industrialReseller') %}
        <span class="price">{{ method.priceAsCurrency }}</span>
    {% endif %}
    {# end conditionally dipslay price #}
  </label>
```

Is this possible?

---

Updated twig code so that the handle has qoutes around it and is not a variable. However still not working.

Above code does not check or set default the expected shipping options. All options are unselected by default

Comment: What is not working specifically? That is, what are you expecting to see and what are you actually seeing? Also, are there other radio inputs with the same name (`shippingMethodHandle`)? If you only have one radio input with the same name, it will always start out checked ...

Comment: @MoritzLost yes there are multiple shipping options. I expect the Regular Freight to be selected by default but when I add the elseif in the conditional I get an error `Variable "regularFreightPrepayAndAddToPurchaseOrder" does not exist.` but that shipping handle does exist.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, you're probably just missing quotes around the shipping handle:

```
{% elseif
  cart.shippingMethodHandle == 'regularFreightPrepayAndAddToPurchaseOrder' and
  (currentUser.isInGroup('distributor') or currentUser.isInGroup('distributorA')) %}
%}
```

Without the quotes, Twig looks for a variable named `regularFreightPrepayAndAddToPurchaseOrder`. Since that variable doesn't exist, this results in an error.

Comment: I can't believe I made that mistake. Thanks for pointing that out. Have added quotes, but it's still not working. Have also updated post code to reflect this.

Comment: @CreateSean Have you checked if the individual conditions are true? You can use `{% dd [some-expression] %}` to check if individual expressions / variables have the expected value. Can you also include the code for the other radio options? Maybe something is going wrong there.